# Python not able to open file with non-english characters in path

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, path, urlencode

I have a file with the following path : D:/bar/クレイジー・ヒッツ！/foo.abc

I am parsing the path from a XML file and storing it in a variable called `path` in the form of `file://localhost/D:/bar/クレイジー・ヒッツ！/foo.abc`
Then, the following operations are being done:

```
path=path.strip()
path=path[17:] #to remove the file://localhost/  part
path=urllib.url2pathname(path)
path=urllib.unquote(path)
```

The error is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\bar\\\xe3\x82\xaf\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\x92\xe3\x83\x83\xe3\x83\x84\xef\xbc\x81\\foo.abc'
```

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Comment: So, how should I handle this?

Comment: Try using a unicode path string instead: `path = path.decode('utf8')` before the rest of your code.

Comment: @Duncan - tried that out, still doesn't work.

Comment: @vr3690 Are you on Windows or not ? Could you confirm this, please.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  - how do I use a different encoding? What should I use here?

Comment: @eyquem - yes, I am using Windows 7

Comment: Well, i am just answer your question via aardvark. It's so coincidence. ：D

Comment: had a similar issue on my Mac. My characters were french. The circumflex characters I had for the file name were not correct french letters. Would get file not found when the output showed the correct path - There was a lost in translation moment between mac and python for these. I went to the file name and gave it the correct circumflex characters and then no issues. This helped me find this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284130/python3-qt-unicode-file-name-problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path in your error is:

```
'\xe3\x82\xaf\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\x92\xe3\x83\x83\xe3\x83\x84\xef\xbc\x81'
```

I think this is the UTF8 encoded version of your filename.

I've created a folder of the same name on Windows7 and placed a file called 'abc.txt' in it:

```
>>> a = '\xe3\x82\xaf\xe3\x83\xac\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\xbc\xe3\x83\xbb\xe3\x83\x92\xe3\x83\x83\xe3\x83\x84\xef\xbc\x81'
>>> os.listdir('.')
['?????\xb7???!']
>>> os.listdir(u'.') # Pass unicode to have unicode returned to you
[u'\u30af\u30ec\u30a4\u30b8\u30fc\u30fb\u30d2\u30c3\u30c4\uff01']
>>> 
>>> a.decode('utf8') # UTF8 decoding your string matches the listdir output
u'\u30af\u30ec\u30a4\u30b8\u30fc\u30fb\u30d2\u30c3\u30c4\uff01'
>>> os.listdir(a.decode('utf8'))
[u'abc.txt']
```

So it seems that Duncan's suggestion of `path.decode('utf8')` does the trick.

---

**Update**

I can't test this for you, but I suggest that you try checking whether the path contains non-ascii before doing the `.decode('utf8')`. This is a bit hacky...

```
ASCII_TRANS = '_'*32 + ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(32,126)]) + '_'*130
path=path.strip()
path=path[17:] #to remove the file://localhost/  part
path=urllib.unquote(path)
if path.translate(ASCII_TRANS) != path: # Contains non-ascii
  path = path.decode('utf8')
path=urllib.url2pathname(path)
```

Comment: It does. But, gives rise to another problem. 
I am finally using the following code to get myself a usable path:

`           path=urllib.unquote(path)
            path=path.decode('utf8')
            path=urllib.url2pathname(path)
`

Which gives rise to this error :

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\\Music\\Pink Floyd\\The Wall Disc 1\\5 - Another Brick in the Wall, Pt. 2.mp3'
`

Any idea what could be the problem with this path?

Comment: @vr3690, might be easier to start a new question and go from there.

Comment: oops. it turns out I was dealing with some old data. That file actually did not exist and was deleted. But I really think your updated code is the way to go. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Provide the filename as a `unicode` string to the `open` call.

How do you produce the filename?

### if provided as a constant by you

Add a line near the beginning of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

Then, in a UTF-8 capable editor, set `path` to the `unicode` filename:

```
path = u"D:/bar/クレイジー・ヒッツ！/foo.abc"
```

### read from a list of directory contents

Retrieve the contents of the directory using a `unicode` dirspec:

```
dir_files= os.listdir(u'.')
```

### read from a text file

Open the filename-containing-file using `codecs.open` to read `unicode` data from it. You need to specify the encoding of the file (because you know what is the “default windows charset” for non-Unicode applications on your computer).

### in any case

Do a:

```
path= path.decode("utf8")
```

before opening the file; substitute the correct encoding if not "utf8".

Comment: It does. But, gives rise to another problem. I am finally using the following code to get myself a usable path: ` path=urllib.unquote(path) path=path.decode('utf8') path=urllib.url2pathname(path) ` Which gives rise to this error : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\\Music\\Pink Floyd\\The Wall Disc 1\\5 - Another Brick in the Wall, Pt. 2.mp3' Any idea what could be the problem with this path?

Comment: Anything for a fellow Floyd fan :) Right before the `open`, please `print(repr(path))` first to ensure that backslashes are as many as they should be. Post back here.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ  ahh. Floyd. Here you go - `u'D:\\Music\\Pink Floyd\\The Wall Disc 1\\5 - Another Brick in the Wall, Pt. 2.mp3'`

Comment: Turns out,the file actually did not exist. I was dealing with some old data. Thanks a lot for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some interesting stuff from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding):

> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
>
> Return the name of the encoding used
>   to convert Unicode filenames into
>   system file names, or None if the
>   system default encoding is used. The
>   result value depends on the operating
>   system: On Mac OS X, the encoding is
>   'utf-8'. On Unix, the encoding is the
>   user’s preference according to the
>   result of nl_langinfo(CODESET), or
>   None if the nl_langinfo(CODESET)
>   failed. On Windows NT+, file names are
>   Unicode natively, so no conversion is
>   performed. getfilesystemencoding()
>   still returns 'mbcs', as this is the
>   encoding that applications should use
>   when they explicitly want to convert
>   Unicode strings to byte strings that
>   are equivalent when used as file
>   names. On Windows 9x, the encoding is
>   'mbcs'.
>
> New in version 2.3.

If I understand this correctly, you should pass the file name as unicode:

```
f = open(unicode(path, encoding))
```

Comment: Ok, I did this : `path=unicode(path,sys.getfilesystemencoding())`

got this error - `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Comment: I think the path should already be a unicode, so you should try path.encode( encoding )

Comment: OK, so it seems that path already is a unicode string. In that case, I would try to encode the path as mbcs: path = path.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()); open(path).read().

Comment: i played around with encoding a bit. Although it solved my initial problem, I now have another problem at hand. Take a look at my comment on the the other answer by MattH