# Decoding error in paths using nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, anaconda

When I run `nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()` with Python 2.7 (Anaconda, Windows) I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + '\\'

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 9:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't have this error when I use Python 3.4.
Maybe I'm wrong but I suspect the path to contain an accent (as there is an accent in my Windows username).

When I add some `print` in `ntpath.py`, nothing is printed I don't know why (?) so I'm unable to debug by myself.

**EDIT:** The `import nltk` is enough to get the error.

Comment: add this line to the top of your script: `#!/usr/bin/env python -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, e.g. https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/lesk.py

Comment: @alvas it does not change anything...

Comment: set locale to utf8? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E26033/glmha.html

Comment: import sys ;reload(sys);sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") before string processing. Or dont touch name use os.walk()

Comment: @alvas I am on Windows

Comment: @SDilmac Your first solution does not change anything. About `os.walk()` I will study the doc to understand, thank you

Comment: or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path i hope helpful

Comment: Can you include the full traceback, not just the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing Python 2 nltk has some issues with non-ASCII paths. Using Python 3 is probably the simplest fix here, at least assuming you don't have too much code that doesn't work in it. It's hard to say for sure, since you didn't include the full traceback, but likely nltk would have to be patched to fix this for Python 2. Otherwise, you would need to avoid paths with non-ASCII characters (meaning avoiding your user directory or changing your username).