# In a Folder, Open Each File With Non-ASCII Characters in Filenames

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
for filename in os.listdir(u'/path/to/my/folder'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # do something about it
```

And I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test/src/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open(filename) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'helloworld\u751f.html'
```

Any idea?

I am using python 2.7.5 if it matters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This other thread could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python not able to open file with non-english characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path)

Comment: Not exactly the same issue.  But I managed to get around the issue without code change but an upgrade to Python 3.4.