# How to open an Image in a directory with Umlaute using Opencv Python imread?

Tags: python, opencv, special-characters

I have some directorys with Umlaute like `"Bänder"` I want to read in. From this question here [Python not able to open file with non-english characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path) , I know that I have to convert my Path to `utf-8`

```
f = 'data\\Bänder'
s = f.encode('utf-8')

#works
open(s)

#does not work
img = cv2.imread(s)
```

Using the encoded version results in the error:

```
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Casting it back to a string, or decoding it will lead to no image read

I am using Windows 10, Python > 3 and Spyder / Anaconda

Comment: You could always just load the contents of the image file into a buffer and run `cv2.imdecode` on that.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so basically reading in the image data with the help of the bulitin function of python "open" ?

Comment: On Ubuntu umlauts work without any conversion. Are you working with windows?

Comment: I am on Windows 10, I added more details to the question

Comment: Hmm, it seems that on my Win 10 box, I can make `cv2.imread('B\xe4nder.png')` work. i.e. using a Latin-1 codepage.

Comment: so instead of using the encode 'utf-8' I should use latin-1 ?