# ASCII codec error Can't upload files django apache and redhat

Tags: django, apache, django-models, fedora

When I tried to upload a file, my page shows this:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

os.stat(path)

u'/opt/djangoproject/ConvocatoriaESCA/media_cdn/Luis \xc1ngel Garc\xeda Ramos/Comprobante_Ingl\xe9s_Luis_\xc1ngel_Garc\xeda_Ramos.pdf'
```

My path to upload Files in models.py have:

```
def upload_location_comprobante_ingles(instance, filename):
    filename = u"Comprobante_Inglés %s %s.pdf" % (instance.nombre, instance.apellidos)
    return u"%s %s/%s" % (instance.nombre, instance.apellidos, filename)
```

and nombre and apellidos are UTF-8 strings

Comment: You have a problem with your path. Answer is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path#5975944).

Comment: path.decode('utf8') must be set in setting.py or in the model?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in **os.stat(path)**!!

There are two ways how to deploy a django project using Apache.

1. Basic configuration
2. Daemon mode

In the both cases mod_wsgi is used.

By default httpd sets environment variable LANG=C.  Thus the file system encoding will set to **ascii**.

You can checking it using **sys.getfilesystemencoding()**, passed its output to HttpResponse somewhere in your views (or write to a log).

To change LANG environment variable which httpd sets to a mod_wsgi process(es) open file **/etc/sysconfig/httpd** (on Red Hat based OSes). Then comment **LANG=C** or change it to your flavour. This approach will work both in Basic configuration and in Daemon mode.

In addition, Daemon mode supports the 'lang' option of the WSGIDaemonProcess command. In this case you will be able to set different a LANG to different virtualhosts.