# Errno 2 No such file or directory in django

Tags: python, django

When I try to run server in django writing python manage.py runserver , python gives an error which is

```
C:\Users\Alim Írnek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: 
can't open file 'C:\Users\Alim ├ûrnek\PycharmProjects\mysite\manage.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is it because of spaces in my username or something else?

Comment: my guess: you are working on Windows and there's an issue with character encoding in your path: `Alim Írnek`, it's recommended to use english letters to avoid such encoding problems

Comment: got it but it is not possible for now for me to change this, another solution?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this thread it may give you a hint:
[Python not able to open file with non-english characters in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974585/python-not-able-to-open-file-with-non-english-characters-in-path).

Note: Windows as OS is realy painfull for some developement (wait untill you have to install Magento2 on Windows !) but if you got stuck for long time i strongly recommend you to move to `WSL2` on `Windows 10`, the best for now that Microsoft can do for devs like me and you.

ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible it has something to do with the non-ASCII characters in your path?

even in the error code you posted the characters are different.

```
C:\Users\Alim Írnek\
```

vs.

```
C:\Users\Alim ├ûrnek\
```

Wonder if python doesn't recognize those characters as valid paths or is converting them to ascii before reading the filepath and inserting different characters.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.